projecting values of tensor A into tensor B at indices C (pytorch)
Given:
A = tensor([[ 0.4821, -0.3484,  0.0915, -0.1870],
            [ 1.3817,  0.3011,  1.0704,  2.1717]])

B = torch.zeros(2,6)

C =  torch.tensor([[1,2,2,3], [3,7,2,5]]) (same shape of A)

I want to replace values in B by A at indices C where < 6 (B.size(-1))
-> B =[[0, 0.4821, 0.0915, -0.1870, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1.0704, 1.3817, 0, 2.1717]]

Notice that: there are two 2 in the first row of C at the second and third position in A. Here I want to get the max (or sum if you think it's more possible to do)

What you could do is clip the indices such that they do not go above B.size(1) using a scattering operation, in this case, the last element will override the other (only the 2nd 2 will be kept). You also have specialized functions to accumulate via summation or reduce to the maximum value. Let's try this:
torch.zeros(2,6).scatter_(1, C.clip(0,5), A)
tensor([[ 0.0000,  0.4821,  0.0915, -0.1870,  0.0000,  0.0000],
        [ 0.0000,  0.0000,  1.0704,  1.3817,  0.0000,  2.1717]])

But this won't work all the time because indices that are over the max length will be placed at the end. A solution might be to concatenate an additional buffer column to account for the undesired values and then trim the tensor at the end to discard those:
torch.zeros(2,6+1).scatter_(1, C.clip(0,6), A)[:,:-1]
tensor([[ 0.0000,  0.4821,  0.0915, -0.1870,  0.0000,  0.0000],
        [ 0.0000,  0.0000,  1.0704,  1.3817,  0.0000,  2.1717]])

If you want to reduce your scattering differently, you can use torch.scatter_reduce_ and specify the reduce argument:

reduce (str) – the reduction operation to apply for non-unique indices ("sum", "prod", "mean", "amax", "amin")

For example to get the maximum:
torch.zeros(2,7).scatter_reduce_(1, C.clip(0,6), A, reduce='amax')[:,:-1]


Sorry but I don't understand the second approach, now I understand the issue in the first approach but how add one more column makes it work? Thank you :(

I don't think it work. Lets change C =  torch.tensor([[1,2,2,3], [3,5,2,7]]) then 0.3011 should be placed at 5th position in B but it still gives 2.1717 because of clip function

Ops I think you mean torch.zeros(2,6+1).scatter_(1, C.clip(0,B.size(1)), A)[:,:-1] Jaaa clip to len instead of len-1 can fix now I get it

:< Can you make a tutorial. I want to master about tensor manipulation but I don't know where to learn it T.T. Btw can you distinguish for me between scatter and gather function :< @Ivan

Btw the above approach doesn't suppose to get the max value (or sum) among the same indices. As you mentioned there are specialized functions to do that. Can you show me a way :<

You're right, I got the clip max value wrong because I was using the size of B while the zero tensor is created on the fly. I corrected it, anyways the clip max should trim the number of columns - 1. I edited my question with a different reduction to get the max.

Scattering is of the form out[index[i][j]][j] += src[i][j] while gathering is of the form out[i][j] = input[index[i][j]][j].
